# multilevel menu in mvc4 + EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

What the best way to create model multilevel menu in asp.net mvc3 and Code First EF?
In my realization:

```
public class Menu{
public int id{get;set;}
public string Name{get;set;}
public List<Menu> Menus{get;set;}
}
```

But I think, in recursion EF can't bind this model :(

Answer (score 0):

This, in principle should work. I think the Entity Framework is messing with the 's' at the end of the "Menus" word. Try this and tell me whether it was successful:

```
public class Menu{
public int id{get;set;}
public string Name{get;set;}
public List<Menu> SubMenus{get;set;}
}
```